# assign key correctly to value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to map a user defined key to the associated value and it is currently returning undefined for the final (var final). The goal is to collect a user provided input (key) and map it to the associated string from the key:value object and then load a URL using this value. The web page loads incorrectly in the end because the value is undefined. Here is the code:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function onLoad() {

var converts = {
    'apples' : 'green',
    'sky' : 'blue'
    };

var myTextField = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
var itemName = myTextField.value;
var final = converts[itemName];

if (document.getElementById('rad1').checked) {    
window.open("somewebsite" + final + "restofURL", "this is a new window");
}
}
```

Comment: Try using `converts[itemName.trim()]`

Comment: what value of `itemName`?

Comment: 1. try to print itemName (console.log(itemName)) and make sure its correct. 2. just a general tip: its not recommended to use "final" as a var name http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/790vkn2v/ The problem is somewhere you're not showing.

Comment: why on click handler you assign _onLoad_? :-D

Comment: here is the entire code:

Comment: The edit is irrelevant to the problem. You need to show the HTML as well, and an example that reproduces the problem. Edit the jsfiddle I provided until it behaves the same way your own code does.

Comment: here is the full code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neemie/mwq5zykh/

Comment: Are you aware that the `textarea` you're using has a bunch of spaces in it by default?  If you clear those out, it seems to work as intended.  If you don't... it doesn't - @vihan1086's suggestion in the first comment should fix that.

Comment: that's it! - thank you James (and @vihan1086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the textarea has a lot of white-spaces in it by default. If the user adds a space, that could cause problems so we need to trim the string:

```
convert[ itemName.trim() ];
```

This will remove all the bordering whitespace.